# jQuery class selecting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a simple slider. It will have two or more slides. They are all grouped in one div, with overflow: hidden and z-indexes done.

I suggested the slide which will be visible will have class of "active", while the others have "inactive" class. I have a button, which if clicked, should switch classes between slides. Check the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="thumbSlider">
<div class="activeSlider">
  <img class="thumbUnit" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/upperSlider/slider1.jpg">
<img class="thumbUnit" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/upperSlider/slider2.jpg">
<img class="thumbUnit" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/upperSlider/slider3.jpg">
<img class="thumbUnit" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/upperSlider/slider4.jpg">
<img class="thumbUnit" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/upperSlider/slider5.jpg">
<img class="thumbUnit" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/upperSlider/slider6.jpg">
<img class="thumbUnit" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/upperSlider/slider7.jpg">
<img class="thumbUnit" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/upperSlider/slider8.jpg">
<img class="thumbUnit" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/upperSlider/slider9.jpg">
<img class="sliderNext" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/upperSlider/sliderNext.png" >
</div>
<div class="inactiveSlider">
<img class="thumbUnit" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/upperSlider/slider8.jpg">
<img class="thumbUnit" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/upperSlider/slider1.jpg">
<img class="thumbUnit" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/upperSlider/slider2.jpg">
<img class="thumbUnit" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/upperSlider/slider3.jpg">
<img class="thumbUnit" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/upperSlider/slider4.jpg">
<img class="thumbUnit" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/upperSlider/slider5.jpg">
<img class="thumbUnit" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/upperSlider/slider6.jpg">
<img class="thumbUnit" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/upperSlider/slider7.jpg">
<img class="thumbUnit" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/upperSlider/slider9.jpg">
<img class="sliderNext" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/upperSlider/sliderNext.png" >

</div>
  </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".sliderNext").click(function(){
$(".activeSlider").addClass("inactiveSlider").removeClass("activeSlider");
var $next = $(".inactiveSlider").next();
    if($next.length == 0){
    $(".inactiveSlider").first().addClass("activeSlider").removeClass("inactiveSlider");
    }
    else {
    $next.addClass("activeSlider").removeClass("inactiveSlider");
    }
});
```

Problem is, on first click on "sliderNext", the classes activeSlider and inactiveSlider, are swapped between the divs. But on second click, it doesn't.

Comment: Typo: `removeClass(".activeSlider");` should be `removeClass("activeSlider");`

Comment: If you are showing / hiding your elements, consider using `$(...).toggle();`

Comment: @Jaay can you please tell how it will fit in my example?

Comment: $(".activeSlider").toggleClass("inactiveSlider activeSlider");

Comment: what do you mean with "it doesn't properly select classes"?

Comment: on first click on "sliderNext", the classes activeSlider and inactiveSlider, are swapped between the divs. But on second click, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've got a logical problem in your code - using console.log we can see, that next.length == 0 never occurs. this is because the selector always returns the first 'inactiveSlider's next node.

here's my solution: 
http://jsfiddle.net/vsjb6pbd/2/

```
$(".sliderNext").click(function () {
    $(".activeSlider").toggleClass("inactiveSlider activeSlider");
    var $next = $(this).parent().next();
    console.log($next);
    if ($next.length === 0) {
        console.log("now i'm here");
         $(".inactiveSlider:first").addClass("activeSlider").removeClass("inactiveSlider");
    } else {
        console.log("now i'm there");
        $next.addClass("activeSlider").removeClass("inactiveSlider");
    }
});
```

i changed your next variable, by selecting `$(this).parent().next();`
$(this) is your clicked element - a child of your slide div
.parent then selects the parent of your clicked element, which would be the slide div. 
.next - well you already now this one.

another option would be, to toggle the classes AFTER you selected the next slide ...

Comment: of course - you should consider using toggle class not only once, but everywhere... i was just lazy copy&pasting ;)

Comment: another point to have here is jQuery should have nextOrLast function, instead of using length.

Answer (score 2):

`addClass` and `removeClass` expect class names, not selectors. `.activeSlider` is a *selector*. `activeSlider` is a class name.

```
....removeClass(".activeSlider");
```

needs to be

```
....removeClass("activeSlider");
```

Comment: Thank you. Fixed the typo, still the slider isn't working after first click on "sliderNext"

Comment: This is what the close reason of *a simple typographical problem* is for. I've down voted you because this answer is nothing more than a comment to accompany that close vote.

Answer (score 1):

In the second line when you do it:

```
$(".activeSlider").addClass("inactiveSlider").removeClass("activeSlider");
```

All div elements will have a class **inactiveSlider**. So when you do

```
var $next = $(".inactiveSlider").next();
```

You will always get the second .thumbSlider child.

Looking deep into your logic I found that you need to change it a little bit:

```
$(".sliderNext").click(function(){

    // Remove this line. It makes all sliders inactive
    // $(".activeSlider").addClass("inactiveSlider").removeClass("activeSlider");

    // Get the next inactive slider from the active one
    var $next = $(".activeSlider").next();

    // I moved the first line to here
    $(".activeSlider").addClass("inactiveSlider").removeClass("activeSlider");

    // Test if there's an inactive from the active one
    if($next.length == 0){
        $(".inactiveSlider").first().addClass("activeSlider").removeClass("inactiveSlider");
    } else {
      $next.addClass("activeSlider").removeClass("inactiveSlider");
    }
});
```

Look this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3ruvaL6z/)

Comment: Fixed my mistake! It's working now... see the fiddle